# Efficientily forward porting changes of core theme: Git Three Way Merge with Core Changes?

Tags: git, magento, magento2

I am working on Magento (not asking this on magento.stackexchange.com because it is more git related).

Sometimes it is unavoidable to change files from core theme. (by copying to the own theme of course)

It works (simplyfied) like this

1. That is the core file: `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/message.phtml`
2. I copy it to `app/design/frontend/My/Theme/default/Magento_Theme/templates/message.phtml`
3. Now I make a git commit of the file "Original taken from the core"
4. Now I make my changes
5. When upgrading to a new Magento version, the `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/message.phtml` is probably updated (via composer, the file is not in my git)
6. Now I am looking for a way to either port the new changes from the core (from the vendor folder) to my custom file. Or to re-apply all my changes to a fresh copy from the core.

I was already pretty successful with creating a patch between my "Original 
taken from core" commit and the current version, copying the new original from core and applying the patch. I did all this manually and I am wondering if there is an more automated way.

Comment: *"Sometimes it is unavoidable to change files from core theme."* - can you give an example? I can't think of any

Comment: When overwriting .phtml files for example - I am talking about copying the files to my theme - not changing them directly in the core. But then still I would like to port updates to the core to my theme.

Comment: I see - great question!

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to carry private versions of upstream source, carry them with the upstream source, in a local history based on the upstream one.  Then, when upstream comes up with a new version, git can merge the changes automatically better than anything, or at least as well.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately I am not sure how to do this in a Magento project .. cause copying template files to a private theme is standard there - from various points in the file system.

Comment: Git doesn't track files separately, there's only the dag of full-project snapshots-aka-commits, and references to currently-interesting snapshots in the dag.  All other information is derived by efficiently examining that and schlepping interesting bits of it around among repositories.